# How to compare Chinese strings in English environment?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization

I'm trying to compare Chinese strings with 
`NSString - (NSComparisonResult)localizedStandardCompare:(NSString *)string` method.

It works correctly if the system language is set to Chinese. But in English language environment, the strings is compared by something like unicode number. How can I compare strings with Chinese style in English environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `- (NSComparisonResult)compare:(NSString *)aString options:(NSStringCompareOptions)mask range:(NSRange)range locale:(id)locale` instead.

Comment: What is the locale we have to provide? I want to compare English and German strings.