# Unable to compare some foreign language using compare:

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsstring

I am dealing with some foreign language filenames such as `내가 해결할 수없는 생각.docx`.

When I compare the filenames with `NSString`'s `compare:` it returns `False` even for the same stored filename. Strange part is that it returns `True` with `caseInsensitiveCompare:`.

I have tested by passing `English` filenames, it works good `compare:`, showing the filenames are not capitalized by any chance.

I can compare with this *not the best of way*, but there are many cases where `NSPredicate` also fails to compare the two strings.

My question is how to compare these non-english text?

Is there any other better way to compare, or do I need to use a loop and use `caseInsensitiveCompare:`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787570/how-to-compare-chinese-strings-in-english-environment

Comment: @johnykumar: Thank you for your link. But what to do with `NSPredicate`?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/librarY/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSPredicate/predicateWithBlock:

Comment: @IanMacDonald: That doesn't help...

Comment: If you create an `NSPredicate` with a block instead of a string, you will be provided the ability to do more powerful things and construct your own method of comparison within the block.

Answer (score 1):

`comare:` doesn’t return “`True`” or “`False`” (or `YES` or `NO`). It returns a value of type `NSComparisonResult`, which can be `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedDescending`. Is there maybe some confusion here having to do with the corresponding integer values of these three values (`-1`, `0`, and `1`, respectively)?